# Getting indices of both zero and nonzero elements in array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find the indicies of both the zero and nonzero elements of an array.

Put another way, I want to find the complementary indices from `numpy.nonzero()`.

The way that I know to do this is as follows:

```
indices_zero = numpy.nonzero(array == 0)
indices_nonzero = numpy.nonzero(array != 0)
```

This however means searching the array twice, which for large arrays is not efficient. Is there an efficient way to do this using numpy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you already have the range for use `numpy.arange(len(array))`, just get and store the logical indices:

```
bindices_zero = (array == 0)
```

then when you actually need the integer indices you can do

```
indices_zero = numpy.arange(len(array))[bindices_zero]
```

or

```
indices_nonzero = numpy.arange(len(array))[~bindices_zero]
```

Comment: For what I needed, @bmu provided the best answer.  However, your answer exactly answers my question, so I'll give this one the checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
In [82]: a = np.random.randint(-5, 5, 100)

In [83]: a
Out[83]: 
array([-2, -1,  4, -3,  1, -2,  2, -1,  2, -1, -3,  3, -3, -4,  1,  2,  1,
        3,  3,  0,  1, -3, -4,  3, -5, -1,  3,  2,  3,  0, -5,  4,  3, -5,
       -3,  1, -1,  0, -4,  0,  1, -5, -5, -1,  3, -2, -5, -5,  1,  0, -1,
        1,  1, -1, -2, -2,  1,  1, -4, -4,  1, -3, -3, -5,  3,  0, -5, -2,
       -2,  4,  1, -4, -5, -1,  3, -3,  2,  4, -4,  4,  2, -2, -4,  3,  4,
       -2, -4,  2, -4, -1,  0, -3, -1,  2,  3,  1,  1,  2,  1,  4])

In [84]: mask = a != 0

In [85]: a[mask]
Out[85]: 
array([-2, -1,  4, -3,  1, -2,  2, -1,  2, -1, -3,  3, -3, -4,  1,  2,  1,
        3,  3,  1, -3, -4,  3, -5, -1,  3,  2,  3, -5,  4,  3, -5, -3,  1,
       -1, -4,  1, -5, -5, -1,  3, -2, -5, -5,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -2, -2,
        1,  1, -4, -4,  1, -3, -3, -5,  3, -5, -2, -2,  4,  1, -4, -5, -1,
        3, -3,  2,  4, -4,  4,  2, -2, -4,  3,  4, -2, -4,  2, -4, -1, -3,
       -1,  2,  3,  1,  1,  2,  1,  4])

In [86]: a[-mask]
Out[86]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I needed.  I forgot that I could do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a built-in numpy method for accomplishing this, but you could use an old-fashioned `for` loop, I believe. Something like:

```
indices_zero = []
indices_nonzero = []

for index in xrange(len(array)):
    if array[index] == 0:
        indicies_zero.append(index)
    else:
        indicies_nonzero.append(index)
```

Something like this should accomplish what you want, by only looping once.

Comment: Yes this would work, but if written in python it will likely be slower than calling the numpy routine twice.  I could do this in cython to get the performance, but I was hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: I did not work with numpy, but just as a idea... Has a numpy vectorized operations? If so, you can get vector of logical values were zeros are, invert it (fast) and take vector of logic value with non-zero values. Applying this values to array in matrix form will give you both vectros faster than simple iteration.