# get indicies of non-zero elements of 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

From [Getting indices of both zero and nonzero elements in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598879/getting-indices-of-both-zero-and-nonzero-elements-in-array), I can get indicies of non-zero elements in a 1 D array in numpy like this:

`indices_nonzero = numpy.arange(len(array))[~bindices_zero]`

Is there a way to extend it to a 2D array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## You can use `numpy.nonzero`

The following code is self-explanatory

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 5, 1],
              [3, 0, 0]])
nonzero = np.nonzero(A)
# Returns a tuple of (nonzero_row_index, nonzero_col_index)
# That is (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([0, 2, 1, 2, 0]))

nonzero_row = nonzero[0]
nonzero_col = nonzero[1]

for row, col in zip(nonzero_row, nonzero_col):
    print("A[{}, {}] = {}".format(row, col, A[row, col]))
"""
A[0, 0] = 1
A[0, 2] = 1
A[1, 1] = 5
A[1, 2] = 1
A[2, 0] = 3
"""
```

## You can even do this

```
A[nonzero] = -100
print(A)
"""
[[-100    0 -100]
 [   0 -100 -100]
 [-100    0    0]]
 """
```

## Other variations

### `np.where(array)`

It is equivalent to `np.nonzero(array)` 
But, `np.nonzero` is preferred because its name is clear

### `np.argwhere(array)`

It's equivalent to `np.transpose(np.nonzero(array))`

```
print(np.argwhere(A))
"""
[[0 0]
 [0 2]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 0]]
 """
```

Comment: You should expand your answer a bit explaining what it does and what `numpy` function it uses.

Comment: `np.nonzero`, or its alias `np.where` hardly needs special explanation..

Comment: Look at `np.argwhere` for another interesting trick (check its code)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. 
I changed (x, y) to (row, col) for clarity. But the code should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

```py
A = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 5, 1],
              [3, 0, 0]])

np.stack(np.nonzero(A), axis=-1)

array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0]])
```

np.nonzero returns a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension of a, containing the indices of the non-zero elements in that dimension.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html

np.stack joins this tuple array along a new axis. In our case, the innermost axis also known as the last axis (denoted by -1).

The axis parameter specifies the index of the new axis in the dimensions of the result. For example, if axis=0 it will be the first dimension and if axis=-1 it will be the last dimension.

New in version 1.10.0.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html

Comment: Adding some explanations is highly encouraged.