# Select random non zero elements from each row of a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2d array

```
a = array([[5, 0, 1, 0],
           [0, 1, 3, 5],
           [2, 3, 0, 0],
           [4, 0, 2, 4],
           [3, 2, 0, 3]])
```

and a 1d array

```
b = array([1, 2, 1, 2, 2])
```

which (`b`) tells how many non-zero elements we want to choose from each row of the array `a`.

For example, `b[0] = 1` tells us that we have to choose 1 non-zero element from `a[0]`, `b[1] = 2` tells us that we have to choose 2 non-zero elements from `a[1]`, and so on.

For a 1d array, it can be done using `np.random.choice`, but I can't find how to do it for a 2d array, so I have to use a `for` loop which slows the computation.

I want the result as 2d array as

```
array([[5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 5],
       [2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 4],
       [3, 2, 0, 0]])
```

Here, we have 1 element in row 1, 2 elements in row 2, 1 element in row 3 and so on as given in array b.

Comment: What if the number of non-zero items doesn't match with random number in `b`?

Comment: @Kasramvd The numbers in `b` are not random,  it is the integer value of 80% of the number of non-zero elements in a for each row. Like for `row 1`  number of non-zero element is `2`, `80% of 2` is `1.6`, `int(1.6)` is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Competitive Programming problem.

I don't think that you can achieve the results using numpy.random.choice (I may be wrong).

Anyways, think of it like this. To select `x` number of non-zero elements from a 1D array of size `n`, it will be of O(n) complexity in the worst case. And, for a 2D array it will be O(n^2) if you follow the same naive approach.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092848/get-indicies-of-non-zero-elements-of-2d-array) post is almost similar to your question, but numpy.nonzero also is an O(n^2) function.